# the size of SIFT descriptors

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sift, descriptor

did all vectors of descriptors that extracted by SIFT descriptor for the same image have the same length or size of descriptors is varied because I misunderstand this point?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general all the keypoint descriptors extracted from an image have the same length. The descriptor length might be a parameter of the method, but typically it is fixed before the extraction (e.g., 128 numbers for SIFT).